# Creator email notifications for updates to documents in Sharepoint Library

Tags: document-library, infopath

I have a Sharepoint document library, in which docs are created via an infopath form.

It is working ok, but I need to add email alerts for the document creator. They will require an email every time a change is made to the document they created.

Is this possible? Is it a Sharepoint library setting or something done in the form set up?

Thanks

EDIT: To clarify: the InfoPath form has a "Requested By" field which records the original submitting user.

Answer (score 1):

Users may set alerts to the list with the setting to notify them on change of their documents.

Alternatively use a list workflow. A list workflow requires no action from the user as it applies to all items in the list. It can be designed using Sharepoint designer 2010 in a few clicks.

**Example**

In SPD use the workflow action for mail to send an email. In the "To:" field a lookup for the "created by" field. This field contains the SP user who created the item and can be used to mail to. Fill in the other fields as needed. I.e. in the body and the subject field you might want to put the name of the document changed (again with a lookup, this time by pressing the ... Button).

Then go to the workflow settings and set it to start on change of items.

Don't forget to save AND publish.